# Shell/Bash - Script continua antes de terminar a linha que está rodando

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Tenho um script shell/bash que funciona perfeitamente para fazer backups, o problema é que tenho arquivos grandes que estão dando problemas na execução do script. O script tem q compactar o arquivo no formato `tar.gz` e ele faz isso, mas quando chega em 6GB +ou- o script continua compactando o arquivo mas passa pras próximas linhas e o backups fica com falhas, o servidor deve ter um `set_time_limit;` igual no php, no arquivo php que chama o shell/bash eu uso `set_time_limit(0);` e funciona muito bem, o shell/bash tem algo parecido tb ?

O script:

```
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
$MYSQLDUMP -u $DBUSER -h $DBHOST -p$DBPASS $DBNAME | gzip > $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

ssh $USER_SSH@$HOST_SSH "tar -zcf - $HOME" > $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz

tar -zcf $TIMESTAMP.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

SUCCESS=$?

rm $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz
rm $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz
```

Não coloquei as váriaveis pois acho q não é necessário.

Antes de terminar o `tar` ele remove os 2 arquivos das linhas finais ... se o arquivo for inferior a cerca de 6 GB ou 7GB isso não acontece

Comment: Não entendi porque limitar o tempo. Pois nesse caso não poderia interromper o processo? A sua questão não seria sobre execução síncrona?

Comment: O **GNU tar** possui um parâmetro chamado `--checkpoint` com o qual poderá criar um callback. Assim, a execução seguinte só seria invocada quando o processo corrente completar.

Comment: @DanielOmine tem algum exemplo do uso desse --checkpoint ? se puder posta uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas alternativas.

Uma delas é o comando [`timeout`](http://ss64.com/bash/timeout.html).

> Executa um comando com um limite de tempo, executa o comando fornecido
>   e finaliza se ele ainda estiver em execução após o intervalo de tempo
>   especificado.
>
> Onde o limite de tempo pode ser:
>
> - `s` para segundos (padrão)
> - `m` para minutos
> - `h` por horas
> - `d` para dias

Sintaxe:

```
timeout <opções> <duração> <comando> <args..>
```

Exemplo:

```
timeout 10 ./script1.py
```

O exemplo acima vai executar o arquivo `script1.py`, se depois de *10s* o arquivo ainda estiver em execução, o mesmo é encerrado.

Uma outra alternativa é:

```
./script1.py& sleep 10; kill $!
```

A linha acima vai executar o arquivo `script1.py` em segundo plano, esperar *10* segundos e  encerrar o processo especificando o *pid* em `$!`.

### **Edição**

Você também pode num *loop* verificar o retorno da função responsável por fazer o *backup*, após o término perguntar ao usuário se ele deseja prosseguir com a execução do *script* ou não.

```
#!/bin/bash

function iniciarBackup(){
    echo "Iniciando backup..."

    MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
    $MYSQLDUMP -u $DBUSER -h $DBHOST -p$DBPASS $DBNAME | gzip > $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

    ssh $USER_SSH@$HOST_SSH "tar -zcf - $HOME" > $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz
    tar -zcf $TIMESTAMP.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

    return 0
}

function deletarArquivos(){
    rm "$TIMESTAMP.sql.gz"
    rm "$TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz"
}


iniciarBackup

while true ; do
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "Operação de backup concluída!"
     read -p "Você deseja deletar os arquivos? [S/N]" resposta
     case $resposta in
        [Ss]* ) deletarArquivos; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Você deseja deletar os arquivos? [S/N]";;
    esac
   fi
done

echo "Fim do script."
```

Comment: @A.S. Aqui pra mim funcionou, você pode postar o código no http://pastebin.com/ e colocar o link aqui?

Comment: @A.S. Isso é estranho, tente o seguinte: http://pastebin.com/CaKyQ2xb Veja se ele pede a tua confirmação.

Comment: @A.S. Deu certo agora? o *script* pede confirmação para remover os arquivos?

Comment: @A.S. Qual o sistema de arquivos você usa nesse servidor? outra coisa, execute novamente o *script* e veja os *logs* do sistema ([**aqui**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15647/where-can-i-find-the-kernel-logs) mostra algumas formas).

Comment: como verifico o sistema de arquivos ? e sobre o log do sistema tentei das maneiras do link q mandou mas só tenho acesso a uma, o comando tail, mas não tive permissão rodando ele...

Comment: @A.S. `stat -f -c %T /` no terminal. Já que você não tem acesso aos *logs*, faça o seguinte: 1) na linha do `tar  -zc...` substitua por `tar -czvf $TIMESTAMP.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz 1 2> foobar.log`. 2) Execute o *script*.  3) O `tar` vai criar um *log*, `foobar.log`, veja o conteúdo desse arquivo, assim: `cat foobar.log` e veja se há erros.

Comment: @A.S. Então.. conseguiu ver os aquivos de log?

Comment: esse é log @stderr: `tar: Removing leading /' from member names
tar: Removing leading /' from member names
tar: /home/w_admin/backups/v2_1472236567.sql.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
rm: cannot remove /home/w_admin/backups/v2_1472236567.sql.gz': No such file or directory`

Comment: @A.S. Já é algo. :) A primeira mensagem é um aviso ([veja](http://serverfault.com/a/200806)), agora a segunda, parece indicar que por alguma razão um ou mais arquivos não puderam ser adicionados ao `tar`, ([**veja**](http://superuser.com/a/169281/219655)). Se no `tar` tiver a *flag* `-v` retire e rode novamente o *script*! Já tentou rodar o *script* com privilégios? ex.: `sudo script1.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pedir para o cliente SSH informar o servidor que ele está ativo *(alive)* a cada `n` segundos, inserindo a seguinte opção:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 $USER_SSH@$HOST_SSH ...
```

Neste exemplo: 30 segundos. O parâmetro é `-o ServerAliveInterval=<tempo-em-segundos>`.

Maiores detalhes [aqui](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/ssh/disable-timeout).

Comment: se eu coloco o `-o ServerAliveInterval=30` ele exclui os arquivos ainda mais rápido, to tentando o contrario doq vc falou, colocando `-o ServerAliveInterval=3600`, vamos ver...

Comment: Não funcionou tb :/

Comment: `tar: ServerAliveInterval=3600: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

Comment: Você tá especificando o parâmetro no comando ssh ou no comando tar?!

Comment: estou colocando o comando desse jeito: `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=3600 $USER_SSH@$HOST_SSH "tar -zcf - $HOME" > $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz`

Comment: Tentei desta maneira e funcionou normalmente (meu servidor SSH está escutando na porta 9595): `ssh 192.168.1.2 -p9595 -lvictor -o ServerAliveInterval=50 "tar cfzv /tmp/abc.tgz /tmp/abc" > abc.log`